# Error encountered while starting the network in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I received this error upon starting my network.

Command Used :
./byfn.sh up

Operating System :
Windows 10 pro

Error :

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat
>   scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown ERROR !!!! Test
>   failed

Comment: did you export the path after downloading the binaries:  export PATH=<path to download location>/bin:$PATH    follow https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/samples.html#download-platform-specific-binaries

Comment: Yes, I did. The issue was with my docker, it was not able to search for the directory script. As soon as I reset my credentials for docker and restart it, it worked fine.